# Postmates API "BadRequest - 400 version too old" using the ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, postmates

So we're using the ruby gem with a sinatra CRUD app to make a delivery quote and subsequent delivery for third party "food gifting".

Here is the HTML form sending the post request:

```
<form method="POST" action="/v1/customers/10/delivery_quotes">
  <input type="hidden" name="request[requestor_id]" value="10"/>
  <input type="text" name="request[pickup_name]" placeholder="Restaurant Name"/>
  <input type="text" name="request[pickup_address]" placeholder="Restaurant Address"/>
  <input type="text" name="request[pickup_phone_number]" placeholder="Restaurant Phone #"/>
  <textarea type="text" name="request[manifest]" placeholder="Your order"></textarea>
  <input type="text" name="request[dropoff_phone_number]" placeholder="Your Phone #"/>
  <input type="text" name="request[dropoff_address]" placeholder="Your Address"/>
  <input type="text" name="request[dropoff_name]" placeholder="Your Name"/>
  <input type="text" name="request[dropoff_notes]" placeholder="Notes"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Request" />
</form>
```

And the POST route in our controller:

```
post '/v1/customers/:customer_id/delivery_quotes' do
  @client = Postmates.new
  @request = Request.create!(params[:request])

  from = params[:request][:pickup_address]
  to = params[:request][:dropoff_address]

  post_quote = @client.quote(pickup_address: from, dropoff_address: to)
  @quote = Quote.new(request_id: @request.id, detail_hash: post_quote)

  if @quote.save
    redirect "/"
  else
   erb :"/requests/new"
  end
end
```

In the stack trace the error is being thrown in the Faraday Middleware but I've checked all of the versioning and it all lines up. Has anyone else experienced this error?

Comment: Can you send the exact error you are getting back?

Comment: I think it's probably an issue with the gem wrapper you are using; have you tried hitting Postmates API without using the ruby gem?

Comment: Are you using ":customer_id" or your actual customer ID? You can find it here: https://postmates.com/developer/apikey